# is ∀x∃y(Lxy) and ∃x∀yLyx provable from each other?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, predicate-logic, quantifiers

The proof I have is :

$\begin{aligned}1&\ &\forall x\exists yLxy\\  
2&\ &\exists y\ \text{(Lay)}\ \forall E_1\\ 
3&\ &\text{Assume Lab}\\  
4&\ & \forall y Lyb\ \forall I_3∀yLyb\\ 
5&\ &\exists x\forall yLyx \exists I_4\\ 
6&\ & \exists x\forall yLyx ∃x∀yLyx\ \exists E_2 ∃, 3–5 \\\end{aligned}$

But I don't know if steps 4 and 5 are proper application of the universal and existential introductions.

Comment: It is not true if your universe is empty.  $\forall x \exists y Lxy$ is then vacuously true, but $\exists y \forall x Lyx$ is false.

Comment: The way that the second is written relative to the first one is confusing. Much clearer to write $\exists y\forall x Lxy.$ (Also, the implication only goes one way, and it's not the way you're trying to prove.)

Comment: No. They are logically in-equivalent.

Comment: The conclusion of your alleged deduction doesn't match the conclusion inthe title.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true.  Let $Lxy$ be $x=y$ and the universe be $\{1,2\}$  Then $\forall x \exists y Lxy$ is true because for whatever $x$ you pick you can make $y$ be the same.  $\exists x \forall y Lyx$ is false because whatever $x$ you pick there is an unequal $y$.

Comment: I'm a little confused, I thought that two sentences A and B are provably equivalent if and only if each can be derived from the other, A ⊢ B and B ⊢ A.

Comment: And I have shown an example where one is true and the other false. They are not equivalent.

Comment: If $A$ is true and $B$ is false, then $B$ cannot be derived from $A$.

Comment: @GEdgar so ∃∀ cannot be derived from ∀∃ since one is true and the other is false, but can ∀∃ be derived from ∃∀?

Comment: As long as the universe is nonempty, it can.  Write it as $\exists y \forall x Lxy$ by swapping the bound variables.  The $y$ that this says exists satisfies the desired conclusion.